# Construct a non-Hamiltonian Graph

Tags: graph-theory

How do I constuct a $G$ non Hamiltonian graph for any $n≥3 $ $( |V(G)|=n )$, in which $\delta(G)$ is at least $(n-1)/2$? Is there any algorithm for that? Do I have to use mathematical induction?

When $n=3$ there is a non-Hamiltonian graph that satisfies the statement.

Comment: does $\delta$ stand for the tree-width of the graph? Or something else?

Comment: It is the minimum degree of the graph

Comment: Surely you mean $n\ge 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am considering the odd $n$ case, you will figure out the even case.

Take $G=(V,E)$ where we note $V=\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ and

$\forall (i,j)\in[1,\frac{n+1}{2}], (v_i,v_j) \in E$

$\forall (i,j)\in[\frac{n+1}{2},n], (v_i,v_j) \in E$

(Intuitively, you have two complete graphs of size $\frac{n+1}{2}$ which you stuck by one node)

Since you have to go only once through $v_{\frac{n+1}{2}}$, $G$ is certainly not hamiltonian. And the degree requirement is satisfied.

Comment: Also as this graph is 1-connected it not hamiltonian, because hamiltonian graphs are 2-connected.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example for odd $n=2k+1$ would be the complete bipartite graph $K_{k,k+1}$.

It is easy to see that there is no solution for $n=4$, and there is none for $n=6$ either.

In fact I haven't found *any* solution with an even $n>2$.